# Visual Studio 2012 stuck at debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, freeze

i am developing a `WPF .Net Application` using VisualStudio2012. Since today somehow when i try to `debug` (also when i've selected Release) the process hangs beofre the `window` even opens. The last message i see in the `output window` is:

```
'MyProjectvshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'
```

As i already mentioned its a `WPF application` using `MVVM Light` and `EF 4` with an DB Connection to an `MSSQL Server 2012`...

Things i've already tried:

- deleting obj folder and bin folder
- restart VisualStudio 2012
- restart SQL Server
- restart Computer
- Uncheck `Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls` in my `Debugging Options`
- Uncheck `Enable Just My Code` in my `Debugging Options`

Please help me!

Comment: Is VS hanging? Or is your process hanging? If your process, have you put a break point in the first line of your main entry point and F11 to get to each part? How about hitting the pause button to see where the code is frozen?

Comment: VS is not hanging. Pause break didnt think of that... somehow i always am in my saveChanges methode... mby i got an infity loop somewhere...

Comment: Look at the callstack when you pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the Pause button in VS to see where your code is stuck at. Also, you can put a breakpoint at your code's main entry point and F11 until you find your (most likely) infinite loop.

If you use the Pause approach, you can look at your callstack to figure out what got you to that point and where it might be looping/stuck

Comment: yeah.. infinite loop... was quite simple when i recognized it.. wasnt carfully enough with my recursion..

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the connection to MSQSQl sever?
If you provide bad credentials or if your account  doesn't  have sufficient rights, you may experience something like that.
Check your EventViewer to see if you have something there as well.

Try to make a new WPF project something simple(no DB stuff), try to debug it to see if it is going to work.
If it does, in that project add some Db stuff and try again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: making it simple could be very difficult at the end of this big project ;) thx anyway.. already solved it